# Mongodb Muliple averages based on a different column

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Using mongodb aggregate, is there a way to have the query return Weight average on all Scale , an average of Scale 1 , an average of Scale 2 all all returned in the same query?

This is an example of an entry in my data set

```
{ 
   "Profile" : "P1",
   "AvgWeight" : 639,
   "Time" : "2017-04-14T05:17:42.000Z",
   "Scale" : 1,
   "Weight" : 1504,
   "Target" : 680
}
```

My query that I am currently running that is averaging the weight accrost all scales ( Might not help, but better to have more info )

```
 [{
                    "$match": {
                        "Time": {
                            "$gt": moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                            "$lt": moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": {
                            "hour": {
                                "$hour": "$Time"
                            },
                            "day": {
                                "$dayOfYear": "$Time"
                            },
                            "interval": {
                                "$add": [{
                                        "$multiply": [{
                                            "$minute": "$Time"
                                        }]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$multiply": [{
                                                "$hour": "$Time"
                                            },
                                            100
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$multiply": [{
                                                "$dayOfYear": "$Time"
                                            },
                                            10000
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$multiply": [{
                                                "$year": "$Time"
                                            },
                                            10000000
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "time": {
                            "$first": "$Time"
                        },
                        "avgW": {
                            "$avg": "$AvgWeight"
                        },
                        "avgWe": {
                            "$avg": "$Weight"
                        },
                        "avgTarget": {
                            "$avg": "$Target"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "$sort": {
                        "Time": -1
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Adding Expected Response SOmething like

```
[
  {
    "_id : {"hour":1,"day":105,"interval":20971050122},

"time":"2017-04-15T01:22:58.000Z",
    "avgW":646,
    "avgWe":1577,
    "avgTarget":680 , 
    "Scale1" : 100 , 
    "Scale2" : 120 
    } ,
   { "_id":{"hour":1,"day":105,"interval":20771050122},
   "time":"2017-04-15T01:22:55.000Z",
    "avgW":646,
    "avgWe":1335,
    "avgTarget":680 , 
    "Scale1" : 100 , 
    "Scale2" : 120 } 
]
```

But if it is a little different I can handle it, as long all the scales are in the same parent object ( it would be to cpu intensive to post process them to link up the matching groups )

Comment: Can you add the expected json response to the post ? Cant you just group on scale and calculate avg weight ? Something like `{
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$Scale",
           avgWeight: { $avg: "$Weight" }
         }
     }`

Comment: I added the expected/ hoped for response, Would adding a different $group : add it as a different response? I am going to be having 1000's of responses ( a few days worth of data grouped by every minute and shown in a table, so post processing I think would be to cpu intensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the first group into two groups.

First group to calculate weight avg for all scales and second group to do rest of avgs.

Something like:

```
 [{
        "$match": {
            "Time": {
                "$gt": moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                "$lt": moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "scale": "$Scale",
                "hour": {
                    "$hour": "$Time"
                },
                "day": {
                    "$dayOfYear": "$Time"
                },
                "interval": {
                    "$add": [{
                            "$multiply": [{
                                "$minute": "$Time"
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            "$multiply": [{
                                    "$hour": "$Time"
                                },
                                100
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "$multiply": [{
                                    "$dayOfYear": "$Time"
                                },
                                10000
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "$multiply": [{
                                    "$year": "$Time"
                                },
                                10000000
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "time": {
                "$first": "$Time"
            },
            "scaleAvg: {
            "$avg": "$Weight"
        }
    }
 }, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "hour": "$_id.hour",
            "day": "$_id.day",
            "interval": "$_id.interval"
        },
        "time": {
            "$first": "$time"
        },
        "avgW": {
            "$avg": "$AvgWeight"
        },
        "avgWe": {
            "$avg": "$Weight"
        },
        "avgTarget": {
            "$avg": "$Target"
        },
        "scaleAvgs": {
            "$push": {
                "scale": "$_id.scale",
                "scaleAvg": "$scaleAvg"
            }
        }
    }
 }, {
    "$sort": {
        "time": -1
    }
 }]
```

Comment: I think that is exactly what I am looking for, Thanks